# Parameter is not valid on Image.Save

Tags: c#, image, base64

Can anyone see anything wrong here?  I get a "Parameter is not valid" on the 'imageData.Save' line but I suspect the imageData var is wonky earlier than that as I am seeing some argument exceptions inside the imageData object after it gets set.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
    using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/User_Data/asset.png")))
            {
                Image imageData = ResizeImage(image, 120, 120, image.Width, image.Height);
                string base64String = this.ImageToBase64String(imageData, ImageFormat.Png);
                <snip>
            }

public string ImageToBase64String(Image imageData, ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageData.Save(stream, format);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public Image ResizeImage(Image image, int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight, int originalWidth, int originalHeight)
    {
        using (Image image2 = new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight))
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image2))
        {
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            double num = ((double)canvasWidth) / ((double)originalWidth);
            double num2 = ((double)canvasHeight) / ((double)originalHeight);
            double num3 = (num < num2) ? num : num2;
            int height = Convert.ToInt32((double)(originalHeight * num3));
            int width = Convert.ToInt32((double)(originalWidth * num3));
            int x = Convert.ToInt32((double)((canvasWidth - (originalWidth * num3)) / 2.0));
            int y = Convert.ToInt32((double)((canvasHeight - (originalHeight * num3)) / 2.0));
            graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
            ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            using (var parameters = new EncoderParameters(1))
            {
                parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
            }
            return image2;
        }
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of my debugger...this is stopped right after imageData gets  established and right before the ImageToBase64String is called.  Those exceptions within imageData do not crash the app but surely that doesn't look right?
[image]

Comment: Are you getting this error at runtime or compile time? It looks like a valid call.

Comment: The Parameter Invalid error is happening at runtime. (file DOES exist) :)

Comment: adding screen shot of the debugger to try and show the wonkyness with imageData

Comment: this  used to work just fine...it has gotta be something stupid that I'm missing.  just need an extra pair of eyes as I am just not seeing it!

Comment: Are your images all square - same H to W proportion?   An absolute size of (120, 120,) seems odd.

Comment: its for thumbnails, the original image gets scaled down to fit a 120x120 square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you are disposing of `image2` via the `using` block, then trying to use it outside the method.  If you examine `ImageData` you will see all sorts of bad data and exceptions:

[image]

Dont dispose of it if you are returning it; the calling code will be responsible for disposing if it when it is done with it:

```
//using (Image image2 = new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight))
Image image2 = new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image2))
{
    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    ...
}
return image2;
```

---

There is a simpler way to scale an image and that codec/quality param code is doing nothing.

```
public Image ResizeImage2(Image image, int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight)
{
    // org size is already available
    Size orginalSize = image.Size;
    Size newSize = Size.Empty;
    float scale;

    if (canvasWidth != 0)
    {
        scale = (float)orginalSize.Height / orginalSize.Width;
        newSize = new Size(canvasWidth, Convert.ToInt32(scale * canvasWidth));
    }
    else if (canvasHeight != 0)
    {
        scale = (float)orginalSize.Width / orginalSize.Height;
        newSize = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(scale * canvasHeight), canvasHeight);
    }     

    //using (Image image2 = new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight))
    Image image2 = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image2))
    {
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height);

        return image2;
    }
}
```

This scales the image passed based on a target Width or Height with a few less variables.  The codec stuff was removed because you would use that with the Save method:

```
using (Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Temp\BigHead.jpg"))
{
    // resize img to the height of a PicBox
    Image imageData = ResizeImage2(img, 0, pb2.Height);
    // winforms show img
    pb2.Image = imageData;

    // get codec
    ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
        .FirstOrDefault(z => z.MimeType == "image/jpeg");
    using (var qparam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L))
    {
        EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encParams.Param[0] = qparam;
        imageData.Save(@"C:\Temp\BigHead_thumb.jpg", codec, encParams);

        // test: no encoder
        imageData.Save(@"C:\Temp\BigHead_thumb2.jpg");
    }
    // ToDo: dispose of returned image
}
```

The calling code can look at the image and decide whether to scale to Height or to Width.  Then the `Image.Save` method uses the Encoder if you want to specify a non default quality level.

The resulting file sizes reflect the impact of the encoder: 72k for the default method, 194k using the Quality Param.

Comment: Plutonix, again!  <head smack>  that was indeed the problem!  Thank you again for your time here!

Comment: Your code is just using the default settings.  If you compare filesize, you will likely see a difference.  Yours is not wrong, it just isnt using it